# User with two ratings and pages for the same account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2492/l8wrtr

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2496/l8wrtr

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a user who registered an account after losing the cookie for their first account. Good catch -- merged!

(The correct way to register is to click the "register" link at the top of the page, but this does require you to hold the cookie for your unregistered account.. which can also be recovered by entering an email on the "forgot login" page.)